# Dask groupby existing index column(s)

Tags: dask

I have a data frame index by column A.
How do I group by using that column with an additional one, e.g. [A, B] without resetting the index?
e.g. what I do today is `df.reset_index().groupby([A,B]).apply(f)` which I think might be not optimal because I am losing the prior indexing.
In my parquet file, A and B are already marked as index. How can I use the existing indexing to make group by A and B more efficient?

Moreover (might be unrelated) I see the CPU usage as very low as if there is a shuffling or io bottleneck.

Comment: Does ddf.groupby([ddf.index, "A"]).sum().compute() not work ? here

Comment: It will work but slow. I am trying to reuse the fact ddf is already indexed

Answer (score 0):

You can always just do a map_partition job as set-index you guarantee each partition has all the values corresponding to that index.

```py
def groupby_apply_func(df):
    return df.reset_index().groupby([A,B]).apply(f)

#### Assumes that ddf has index A
ddf.map_partitions(groupby_apply_func)
```

Comment: I will try. What I am confused about it that I saved the parquet after setting an index so when I load it I don't know if the partition is per index? How can I validate the partitions of dataframe are related to the column value?

Comment: Probably doing a  global value_count on column a and then doing same per partition basis and verifying that the results are equal can do that.

Comment: hi , the method above with map_partitions does not make it faster

Comment: In that case you are probably fast enough all ready as  `map_partitions ` operates in parallel per partition. 

See docs: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html